# Restore Root site collection to another Web Applications sub site in SharePoint2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, restore, export, import

We are using SharePoint 2013 with SQL Server 2012 Single Farm. I have created one Root Site with some custom lists and libraries under some user groups in a Development Environment. I want to move these **Root Site** into Client's Production Server as a **Sub Site** which already contains Root site collection. My question is What is the best method to move these list and libraries without losing relations between tables. Backup/Restore or Export/Imports

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Here this can be achieved using **Export/Import-SPWeb** Powershell Commands

1. Export the Site Collection:

   ```
    Export-SPWeb -Identity http://sitecollection1/sites/asite -Path C:\backups\sc_asite.bak
   ```

2.Create a New Site Collection and add a sub site to that and Import the Backup taken in the previous step.

```
Import-SPWeb http://sitecollection2/sites/bsite/csite  -Path c:\backups\sc_asite.bak
```

after this the new restored site collection can be accessed as a subsite from the url : http://sitecollection2/sites/bsite/csite